# Is there something similar to the dollar sign for reference dragging but between two or more sheets in the same spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a Google Spreadsheet with 10 Sheets named from **1** up to **10**. I also have a sheet called **Result** which has this formula in one of its cells on row 1: `=SUM('1'!G2:G16)`. I would like to drag it downwards so that that row 2 in that same column uses data from sheet **2** instead; like this: `=SUM('2'!G2:G16)`.

Row 3 should have something like `=SUM('3'!G2:G16)`.

Row 3 should have something like `=SUM('4'!G2:G16)`.

And so on, after dragging the first cell downward.

Is there any way to do this with a formula or special char in Google Sheets or do I have to manually edit each cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- create a new sheet and name it **Index** (or use some unneeded column from anywhere)
- populate it like this:

```
+----+---------+
|    |    A    |
+----+---------+
| 1  | Sheet1  |
+----+---------+
| 2  | Sheet2  |
+----+---------+
| 3  | Sheet3  |
+----+---------+
| 4  | Sheet4  |
+----+---------+
| 5  | Sheet5  |
+----+---------+
| 6  | Sheet6  |
+----+---------+
| 7  | Sheet7  |
+----+---------+
| 8  | Sheet8  |
+----+---------+
| 9  | Sheet9  |
+----+---------+
| 10 | Sheet10 |
+----+---------+
```

- then enter your **Result** sheet
- paste this in desired cell **`=SUM(INDIRECT('Index'!$A1;"!G2:G16")))`**
- and drag it down as usual

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by just referencing the current row number e.g.

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(row()&"!G2:G16"))
```